# Install problem indy 10.2.xx on ubuntu 16.04 - lazarus 1.6 - fpc 3.0.0

Tags: 16.04, dpkg, lazarus

I'm use Lazarus for programming I upgrade Ubuntu and lazarus from 15.10 -> 16.04 and 2.6.x -> 3.0.0 but now I can't install indy 10.2.xx again.

the help tell us: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Indy_with_Lazarus

> How to install on debian/ubuntu
>
> 1. cd indy-10.2.0.1/fpc
> 2. chmod +x debian/rules
> 3. touch README
> 4. sudo apt-get install fakeroot
> 5. dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc
> 6. cd ..
> 7. sudo dpkg -i *.deb
> 8. install package indylaz.lpk in lazarus

but when I try for step 5 `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc` I have this error :

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myuser/Appz/indy-10.2.0.3/fpc'
/usr/bin/fpcmake -p -Ti386-linux Makefile.fpc
Processing Makefile.fpc
Error: Target "linux", package "fcl-base" not found
Makefile:2470: recipe for target 'fpc_install' failed
make[1]: *** [fpc_install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myuser/Appz/indy-10.2.0.3/fpc'
debian/rules:99: recipe for target 'install-arch' failed
make: *** [install-arch] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

I have to use indy and why cant create debian package? what is solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. first download indy from the repo
2. Unzip the component from file tar.gz (must be this file, the "zip file" does not work) in directory $(LazarusDir)\components;
3. Go to directory $(LazarusDir)\components\indy-10.2.0.1\ and to create inside them a directory named "saved"
4. Copy the content of the directory $(LazarusDir)\components\indy-10.2.0.1\lazarus\ to directory "saved" created above;
5. Copy the content of directory $(LazarusDir)\components\indy-10.2.0.1\fpc\ to directory $(LazarusDir)\components\indy-10.2.0.1\lazarus, and rewrite all files, ok;
6. Get the content of directory "saved" and copy inside of $(LazarusDir)\components\indy-10.2.0.1\lazarus and you can delete "saved" directory now;
   7.Install the package laz.lpk (available in $(LazarusDir)\components\indy-10.2.0.1\lazarus\indy) by this way:

   - Open the package
   - compile it
   - compile it again / no cleaning / no build all / just plain compile
   - Build Lazarus (but do NOT select any "clean" option)